# Schema markup for logo [application/ld+json]

Tags: php, schema.org

I have implemented for a website the "Schema Logo" according to schema.org.

While testing it both from Goolge Search Console and the google data testing tool (https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?hl=it) the element contains no errors or warning but both tools call it "Element without name".

This is correct or we can define a name for the "snippet" ? I have search google without success.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "url": "<?php echo $this->serverurl(); ?>",
    "logo": "<?php echo $this->serverurl(); ?>/img/logo-microdata.png"
}
```

Comment: create an `@ImageObject`, give it a name and description, then link to `logo/@Organization`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo) it doesn't look like there's a way to provide a name for the logo snippet.

It will still work correctly, it just shows as *Unnamed Item* in Google Search Console.